# AES object key size

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm doing a project which involves creating an application to encrypt data using AES algorithm. In the main function I create an AES object like this;

```
Aes objAes = Aes.Create();
byte[] key = objAes.Key;
byte[] IV = objAes.IV;
```

As far as I've understood AES.Create() function automatically generates a key and an IV.
Knowing that AES is a symmetric algorithm which uses 3 different key sizes:128 bit, 192 bit and 256 bit keys, in this case which kind of key it is creating? I mean what is the size of the key that the AES.Create() function is generating? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost have the answer right under your nose! You already have a byte array for key from `objAes.Key`. If I am not mistaken, it should have a length of 32. So a 32 byte array is 256 bits. You can also check `objAes.KeySize`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I honestly forgot to check that I was storing the key in a byte array.What also confused me was the array part, since an array can hold multiple values I really couldn't tell the exact length the key could have. It seems that the default ones are also 32 bytes for key and 16 bytes for IV. Thanks again